# Erro: The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type ActivitiesListAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragment

Como chamo um Fragment a partir de um BaseAdapter?
Chamarei ele no click do botão, e também devo passar algumas informações.

Estou tentando chamar dessa maneira:

```
Fragment fr = new Fragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Mas ele dá alguns erros:

> The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type ActivitiesListAdapter

Aqui está o código de meu adapter, ele carrega dados de um json, monta uma lista e tem ícones nessa lista que farão alguma ação, no caso, o clique no CheckClickListener, está abrindo uma activity, e passando algumas informações, preciso abrir um fragment ao invés disso e passar as mesmas informações.

```
public class ActivitiesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int        DEPLETED__RED    = 3;
    private static final int        DEPLETED__YELLOW = 2;
    private static final int        DEPLETED__GREEN  = 1;
    private static final DateFormat FMT_DATE;

    static {
        DateFormat iso8601Format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);
        iso8601Format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        FMT_DATE = iso8601Format;
    }

    private ArrayList<JSONObject>   dataProvider     = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    private String[]                jsonColumns;
    private LayoutInflater          inflater;
    private OptionsVO               options;
    private Context                 context;
    private int                     imageResource;
    private BaseListener            imageCallback;
    private String[]                columnsToCompare;
    private ActivitiesListFragment  fragment;

    public ActivitiesListAdapter(JSONArray array, String[] jsonColumns, AbstractListFragment fragment) {
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length(); index++) {
            try {
                this.dataProvider.add(array.getJSONObject(index));
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        this.jsonColumns = jsonColumns;
        this.context = fragment.getContext();
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.options = ApplicationOptionsManager.getOptions(fragment.getActivity(), fragment.getNetworkAction());
        this.fragment = (ActivitiesListFragment) fragment;
    }

    public void setImageCondition(int imageResource, BaseListener imageCallback, String... columns) {
        this.columnsToCompare = columns;
        this.imageResource = imageResource;
        this.imageCallback = imageCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.dataProvider.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.dataProvider.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return ((JSONObject) getItem(position)).optLong("id");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(convertView == null) {
            final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_activities, parent, false);
            view.setTag(R.string.HOLDER, holder);

            holder.icoPlay = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionPlay);
            holder.icoCheck = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionCheck);
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.data = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.data);
            holder.icoAbort = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionAbort);
            holder.icoInfo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.actionInfo);
            holder.icoScaled = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.bar);

            holder.icoPlay.setTag(R.string.HOLDER, holder);
            holder.icoCheck.setTag(R.string.HOLDER, holder);
            holder.icoAbort.setTag(R.string.HOLDER, holder);
            holder.icoScaled.setTag(R.string.HOLDER, holder);
            holder.icoInfo.setTag(R.string.HOLDER, holder);

        }

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(R.string.HOLDER);
        JSONObject item = (JSONObject) getItem(position);

        try {
            item.putOpt("currIndex", position);
        }
        catch(JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.icoPlay.setTag(R.string.JSON, item);
        holder.icoCheck.setTag(R.string.JSON, item);
        holder.icoAbort.setTag(R.string.JSON, item);
        holder.icoScaled.setTag(R.string.JSON, item);
        holder.icoInfo.setTag(R.string.JSON, item);

        int cdDepleted = item.optInt("cdDepleted", -1);
        if(cdDepleted == DEPLETED__RED) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(127, 255, 0, 0));
        }
        if(cdDepleted == DEPLETED__YELLOW) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(127, 255, 255, 0));
        }
        if(cdDepleted == DEPLETED__GREEN) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(127, 0, 255, 0));
        }

        int fkIdArticle = item.optInt("fkIdArticle", -1);
        if(fkIdArticle != -1) {
            holder.icoInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            holder.icoInfo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        boolean flScaled = item.optBoolean("flScaled", false);
        if(flScaled == true) {
            holder.icoScaled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            holder.icoScaled.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        int cdStatus = item.optInt("cdStatus", 1);
        if(cdStatus == 1) {
            holder.icoPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.icoCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.icoAbort.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            holder.icoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.icoCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.icoAbort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holder.icoPlay.setOnClickListener(new PlayClickListener());
        holder.icoCheck.setOnClickListener(new CheckClickListener());
        holder.icoAbort.setOnClickListener(new AbortClickListener());
        holder.icoInfo.setOnClickListener(new InfoClickListener());

        try {
            Date dt = FMT_DATE.parse(item.optString("dtStart"));
            Time tm = new Time(dt, new Date());
            item.putOpt("dtStartFmt", tm.speak());

        }
        catch(ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(this.columnsToCompare != null && this.columnsToCompare.length > 0) {
            final String[] colsToReturn = new String[this.columnsToCompare.length];
            boolean canShow = false;
            int i = 0;
            for(String col : this.columnsToCompare) {
                String optString = item.optString(col);
                if(optString != null && !optString.isEmpty()) {
                    canShow = true;
                }

                try {
                    colsToReturn[i++] = URLDecoder.decode(optString, "UTF-8");
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                }
            }

            if(canShow) {
                holder.icoScaled.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.icoScaled.setImageDrawable(MobileUtils.getDrawable(this.context, this.imageResource));
                holder.icoScaled.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(imageCallback != null) {
                            try {
                                imageCallback.onCallback(new Object[] { colsToReturn });
                            }
                            catch(Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                holder.icoScaled.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        try {
            holder.title.setText(URLDecoder.decode(decodeColumn(item, this.jsonColumns[0]).toString(), "UTF-8"));
            holder.assignCustomData(item, this.jsonColumns);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }

        holder.icoAbort.setTag(R.id.tag_favorite_state, false);
        return(view);
    }

    private CharSequence decodeColumn(JSONObject item, String fieldName) {
        String rawValue = item.optString(fieldName);

        if(this.options != null && this.options.getDomains() != null && this.options.getDomains().length > 0) {

            OptionDomainVO[] domains = this.options.getDomains();
            outer: for(OptionDomainVO domain : domains) {
                String field = domain.getField();

                if(field != null && field.equals(fieldName)) {
                    OptionDomainValueVO[] values = domain.getValues();

                    for(OptionDomainValueVO val : values) {
                        if(val.getValue() != null && val.getValue().toString().equals(rawValue)) {
                            rawValue = val.getLabel();
                            break outer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return rawValue;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView icoPlay;
        ImageView icoCheck;

        TextView  title;
        TextView  data;

        ImageView icoAbort;
        ImageView icoInfo;
        ImageView icoScaled;

        public void assignCustomData(JSONObject item, String[] jsonColumns) {
            this.data.setText(null);
            this.data.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            extractValue(jsonColumns, 1, item);
            extractValue(jsonColumns, 2, item);
            extractValue(jsonColumns, 3, item);
            extractValue(jsonColumns, 4, item);
            extractValue(jsonColumns, 5, item);
            extractValue(jsonColumns, 6, item);
        }

        private void extractValue(String[] jsonColumns, int index, JSONObject item) {
            try {
                String col = jsonColumns[index];
                if(col != null && !col.isEmpty()) {
                    TextView line = getLine(index);
                    if(line != null) {
                        CharSequence value = decodeColumn(item, col);
                        if(value != null && !value.toString().isEmpty()) {
                            try {
                                line.setText(URLDecoder.decode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));
                            }
                            catch(Exception e) {
                            }
                            line.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            }
        }

        private TextView getLine(int index) {
            TextView text = null;

            switch(index) {
                case 1 :
                    text = this.data;
                    break;

            }

            return(text);
        }
    }

    public void clearItems() {
        this.dataProvider.clear();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class PlayClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(R.string.HOLDER);
            final JSONObject json = (JSONObject) v.getTag(R.string.JSON);
            holder.icoPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            AbstractNetworkHandler handler = AbstractNetworkFactory.build(ActivitiesListAdapter.this.context, NetworkAction.ACTIVITIES_SAVE);
            handler.save(json, new HttpJsonObjectListener() {
                public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject object, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {

                    boolean isOk = object.optBoolean("isOk", false);
                    boolean isNew = object.optBoolean("isNew", false);
                    int id = object.optInt("id", -1);

                    if(isOk == true) {
                        try {
                            json.put("cdStatus", 2);
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runRunnableOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                holder.icoPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                holder.icoCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.icoAbort.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });

                        if(isNew == true) {

                            try {
                                json.put("fkIdCallStep", id);
                            }
                            catch(JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runToastOnUiThread("Não foi possível efetuar sua ação", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                }
            }, new HttpFailListener() {
                public void onRequestCompleted(Exception e, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
                    ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runToastOnUiThread("Erro de conectividade", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class AbortClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final JSONObject json = (JSONObject) v.getTag(R.string.JSON);
            final ActivitiesListAdapter self = ActivitiesListAdapter.this;
            final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(R.string.HOLDER);
            // holder.icoPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AbstractNetworkHandler handler = AbstractNetworkFactory.build(ActivitiesListAdapter.this.context, NetworkAction.ACTIVITIES_SAVE);
            handler.save(json, new HttpJsonObjectListener() {
                public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject object, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {

                    boolean isOk = object.optBoolean("isOk", false);
                    boolean isNew = object.optBoolean("isNew", false);
                    int id = object.optInt("id", -1);

                    if(isOk == true) {
                        try {
                            json.put("cdStatus", 1);
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runRunnableOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                holder.icoPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                holder.icoCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.icoAbort.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });

                        if(isNew == true) {

                            try {
                                json.put("fkIdCallStep", id);
                            }
                            catch(JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runToastOnUiThread("Não foi possível efetuar sua ação", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }

                }
            }, new HttpFailListener() {
                public void onRequestCompleted(Exception e, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
                    ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runToastOnUiThread("Erro de conectividade", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class InfoClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HomeActivity home = (HomeActivity) context;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, InfoFragment.class);

            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_INFO", "infomação extra");

            context.startActivity(intent);

            final JSONObject json = (JSONObject) v.getTag(R.string.JSON);
            final ActivitiesListAdapter self = ActivitiesListAdapter.this;
            /*
             * AbstractNetworkHandler handler = AbstractNetworkFactory.build(ActivitiesListAdapter.this.context, NetworkAction.ACTIVITIES_ABORT); handler.update(json, new HttpJsonObjectListener() { public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject object, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) { ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runRunnableOnUIThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { self.dataProvider.remove(json.optInt("currIndex")); self.notifyDataSetChanged(); } }); } }, new HttpFailListener() { public void onRequestCompleted(Exception e, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) { ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runToastOnUiThread("Erro de conectividade", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); } });
             */
        }

    }

    private class CheckClickListener implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final JSONObject json = (JSONObject) v.getTag(R.string.JSON);
            final ActivitiesListAdapter self = ActivitiesListAdapter.this;

            final boolean flQuick = json.optBoolean("flQuick", false);
            final String nmForm = json.optString("nmForm", "sem nmForm");

            AbstractNetworkHandler handler = AbstractNetworkFactory.build(self.context, NetworkAction.ACTIVITIES_QUICK_FINISH);

            handler.update(json, new HttpJsonObjectListener() {
                public void onRequestCompleted(JSONObject object, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
                    ActivitiesListAdapter.this.fragment.runRunnableOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            if(flQuick == false) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);

                                intent.putExtra("fkIdCallStep", json.optInt("fkIdCallStep"));
                                intent.putExtra("currIndex", json.optInt("currIndex"));
                                intent.putExtra("flQuick", flQuick);
                                intent.putExtra("nmForm", nmForm);

                                context.startActivity(intent);

                            }
                            else if(flQuick == true) {
                                // remover da lista do check
                                self.dataProvider.remove(json.optInt("currIndex"));
                                self.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            /*
                             * Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_out_right); anim.setDuration(500);
                             * 
                             * View listItem = self.fragment.getChildAt(itemPosition); listItem.startAnimation(anim);
                             * 
                             * new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { self.dataProvider.remove(itemPosition); self.notifyDataSetChanged(); } }, anim.getDuration());
                             */
                        }

                    });
                }
            }, new HttpFailListener() {
                public void onRequestCompleted(Exception e, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
                    self.fragment.runToastOnUiThread("Erro de conectividade", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void addAll(JSONArray array) {
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length(); index++) {
            try {
                this.dataProvider.add(array.getJSONObject(index));
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendo a sua pergunta. A forma de "chamar" um Fragment é igual qualquer que seja o local de onde o chama.

Comment: Estou tentando chamar dessa maneira: Fragment fr = new Fragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: Mas ele dá alguns erros: The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type ActivitiesListAdapter

Comment: Adicione à pergunta o código do Adapter e o erro que dá.

Comment: coloquei o adapter na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está a tentar aceder ao método `getFragmentManager()` que não existe na classe *ActivitiesListAdapter*.

`getFragmentManager()` é um método que existe nas classes *Activity* e *Fragment*.

O trecho de código postado funciona quando está a ser usado em uma dessas classes.

Neste seu caso terá de se socorrer do objecto `fragment`, passado no construtor, para obter o *FragmentManager*.

```
Fragment fr = new Fragment();

//Linha alterada
FragmentManager fm = fragment.getFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Esta alteração resolverá o erro apresentado.
Se o seu código tem ou não mais algum problema não sei porque ele está muito confuso: acho que o seu *adapter* tem demasiadas responsabilidades.